# Is it possible to route API with condition in 3scale

Tags: routes, header, 3scale

I am very new to Redhat 3scale. We have a requirement to route the API request. I do not have any idea whether it is really possible or not. Searched in internet but did not get much idea on it.

**Requirement**
I have configured an endpoint in 3scale which should be routed to two different backend APIs with respect to a condition.

**Condition**

```
If header x=a 
 then  
 forward req to api-a.com/myapi
else header x=b 
 then  
 forward req to api-b.com/myapi
```

Is it possible?
If yes, how can  I configure that?